# netty socket read timeout does not close the socket

Tags: sockets, timeout, netty

I have an application using netty:tcp listening a port. When a connection comes, it first reads the request and writes the response. In the read part, I have implemented REadTimeout handler, which throws exception if read timeout occurs. Problem is,in a readtimeout exception, I cannot close the socket connection to the client, and it waits on socket forever. How can I kill/close the socket connection between the client when timeout occurs.

In exceptionCought method I am trying to close the connection but as I told socket is still alive. I can check this for the client.

```
@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e)
        throws Exception {
    super.exceptionCaught(ctx, e);
    Channel channel = e.getChannel();
    channel.close();
    //I tried below lines but does not close the socket. 
    //channel.disconnect();
    //NettyHelper.close(channel);
    //org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(channel);
}
```

Comment: Is this method being called?

Comment: Yes it is called. After further investigation at the client side, if client is checking if something arrived with availabile() over socket , it cannot detect if socket is closed. But if it calls read method it understands socket is closed. I guess problem is not in netty.